# While running the Appium-doctor i got an error

Tags: appium, appium-android

info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.15.3
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 14.13.0
**WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!**
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
**WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ adb, android, emulator could not be found because ANDROID_HOME or** ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is NOT set!
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Bin directory of $JAVA_HOME is set
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies completed, 2 fixes needed. ###

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set ANDROID_HOME in bash_profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/kchetan/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/30.0.2:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/30.0.2/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Still failing :( Any working solution chetan?